# Include additional files in an already created zip file using gradle

Tags: gradle

I am creating  a distribution zip containing a jar as an output to my gradle task like below :

```
class MakeDistZipTask extends Zip {
@TaskAction
def DistZip(){
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('gradle.properties').newDataInputStream())
    def versionName = properties.getProperty('versionName')
    println("creating a distribution zip")
    baseName = versionName
    from ('/dist'){ include '*.jar' }
    from('src/main/libs/armeabi-v7a/') {
        include('*')
        into('armeabi-v7a')
    }

    destinationDir = file('dist/')
}
```

}
I execute this task and I get a zip containing jar and armeabi-v7a folder.

Now,I want to customize this zip file without changing this task(required)such  that in the build.gradle project, the user can add files to this zip as per the requirement. I have tried a few solutions available but nothing seems to work so well. I have tried

```
jar{
baseName = 'distZip'
from('src/main/jni/'){
    include('VC*.h')
    into('includes')
}
manifest {
    attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Analytics Library', 'Implementation-Version': version
}
```

Another solution :

```
sourceSets.main.resources{
from('src/main/jni/'){
    include('VC*.h')
    into('includes')
}
```

Also, I used distribution plugin:

```
/*apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'
 version 1.0
 distributions{
jar{
    baseName='distZip'
    contents{
        from('src/main/jni/') {
            include('VC*.h')
            into('includes')
             }
        }
    }
  }
```

No solution adds the file to the zip file. Any pointers

Comment: Could you please provide a complete minimal build file, explain what task you're executing, what you expect it to do and what it does instead?

Comment: Unpack, modify, repack?

Comment: I was going through distribution plugin, wouldn't that be useful here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working using distribution plugin. I added the plugin in the custom plugin project and in my project I added the set of files I want to add to my zip folder like this :

```
distributions{
          myZip{
                 from('path'){
                        include 'file'
                 }
          }
}
```

Comment: myZip is an aready created zip that I created using custom plugin

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I would try something of this form:

```
task newZip(type: Zip)<<{
    basename newZip
    from ziptree(oldZip.zip)
    from filetree(dir/of/new/files)
}
```

You could also do a `DistZip.finalizedBy(newZip)` to ensure newZip is invoked everytime distZip is run.

Comment: I executed this, I execute makeDist task and it says newZip is UP_TO_DATE

Comment: which probably means it *is* up to date? You can run `gradle clean makeDist`

Comment: I did gradlew clean makeDist -i, it says skipping task as it doesnot contain any source files.